# Unable to Commit Changes in Django Project When Including External Repository with Sass Partials

Tags: django, git, github, sass, git-submodules

I am working on a Django project where I need to incorporate an external repository containing Sass partials for styling. To achieve this, I performed a git clone of the Sass partials repository into my Django project's repository.

However, I've encountered an issue where any commits I make do not include the folder from the cloned Sass partials repository. It seems like the changes within the cloned repository are not being tracked or committed within the main Django project.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Cloned the Sass partials repository into my Django project:

```bash
git clone <repository_url>
```

2. Checked that the Sass partials folder is present within my Django project.
3. Made changes to the Sass files and attempted to commit:

```bash
git add .
git commit -m "Made changes to Sass files"
```

However, the commit does not include the changes made in the Sass partials folder.

Additionally, I would like to emphasize that I do not want the changes made to the Sass partials to be committed within the Django project. I intend to maintain the Sass partials repository as a template only.

I suspect there might be something related to the submodule behavior, but I want to ensure that the changes in the Sass partials folder are tracked and included in my commits while keeping the Sass partials repository isolated from the Django project's commits.

Can someone guide me on the correct way to include an external repository, especially Sass partials, within a Django project, ensure that changes in the included repository are properly tracked and committed, and maintain the Sass partials as a template without including their changes in the Django project's commits?

Thank you!